# Increase the size of a Boot Camp partition

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, boot-camp

How do you increase the size of a Boot Camp partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php). It makes a boot DVD you can use to repartition your drive. It supports repartitioning Boot Camp partitions. I've used it twice with no issues for this purpose.

A free solution is [CampTune](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/camptune/). I've never used it so YMMV.

Comment: Do you know if the demo would work to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the demo only shows you how it would repartition the disk. Doesn't allow you to do anything. Maybe someone can think of a solution that doesn't require a third-party application.

Comment: Edited my post to include CampTune.

Answer (score 0):

This guy seems to have it all figured out:

http://dustyreagan.com/how-to-increase-or-decrease-your-boot-camp-partition/

Citing his blog:

To increase the size of your Windows partition use the following steps.

1. Make a backup of your Boot Camp partition from Windows. (optional)
2. Run [Winclone](http://twocanoes.com/winclone/).
3. In [Winclone](http://twocanoes.com/winclone/) create an “Image” to your Mac-formatted external hard drive.
4. Use Boot Camp Assistant to return your drive to a 100% Mac-formatted partition.
5. Use Boot Camp Assistant to make new Boot Camp partition larger than your original partition size.
6. When it asks for Windows disk, quit Boot Camp Assistant.
7. Run Winclone again and “Restore” your Windows image to the new partition.

I like his approach, because it just makes sense - is straightforward and seems like you could not do it any simpler. Also backing up your partition on an external hard drive is always good, in case something goes wrong.

If you follow his directions you will have two backups - a windows backup made by Windows and also a clone made by Winclone.

Besides WinClone he uses BootCamp assistant to create partitions and resize them, so you get as close to the original as possible.

Comment: Please provide some context for the link, including a description of the solution. If it's not too long then paraphrase here, or provide a recap of the process if it's incredibly long/complicated.